# Best index field order with location, range and sort

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

What is the best index order for this document structure:

```
find:
{
    "location": {
        "$geoWithin": {
            "$centerSphere": [
                ["<val>"], "<val>"
            ]
        }
    },
    "isDeleted": "<val>",
    "updatedAt": {
        "$lte": "<val>",
        "$gte": "<val>"
    },
    "_userId": {
        "$nin": ["<vals>"]
    }
}
sort:
{
    "updatedAt": -1
}
```

My assumption is:

```
{
    "isDeleted": 1, // Boolean first because it rules out big chunks of the data set
    "updatedAt": -1, // Rule: place sort fields before range fields
    "location": "2dsphere",
    "_userId": 1
}
```

However I am unsure about the order of `location` in the index.
What is the best order and why?

Comment: Not sure how NoSQL databases uses indexes.. But in general its beter to use high index selectivity first.. Meaning columns which have unique values or a few value comparing with the count to be first in de index over the values which matches more.. in this case location or user_id should be first

Comment: Every value of `location` is practically unique, so high selectivity. And `isDeleted` only has 3 possible values (true, false, not set), also high selectivity. Common sense tells me that `isDeleted` (and all other non-unique fields) should come before `location` because after unique values, there is effectively no ordering happening.